# How to get cropped picture to submit

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I try to make cropping image function from here https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Byurrer/react-load-image-crop/tree/main/?file=/src/ImageLoader.jsx. I try to input to the Setting code like below but image still cannot be save when i click submit.

Problem: selecting image and crop image working except new cropping image not save

Question: how to save new cropping result when submit or how to get cropped image and setNewPicture?

Here's the form code

```
const Setting = () => {
  const [memberData, setMemberData] = useState<MemberDataProps>();
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [expiredDate, setExpiredDate] = useState('');
  const [isPhoneInvalid, setIsPhoneInvalid] = useState(false);
  const [isSubscribe, setIsSubscribe] = useState(false);
  const [newPicture, setNewPicture] = useState<any[]>([]);

  console.log(newPicture);
  const toast = useToast();

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handlePhoneNumber = (value: string) => {
    const isNumber = value.match(/^[0-9\b]+$/);

    setPhoneNumber(value);

    if (isNumber) {
      setIsPhoneInvalid(false);
    } else {
      setIsPhoneInvalid(true);
    }

    if (value.length < 11) {
      setIsPhoneInvalid(true);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('phoneNumber', phoneNumber);
    if (newPicture) {
      formData.append('profilePhoto', newPicture[0]);
    }
    formData.append('subscribeNewsletter', String(isSubscribe));

    try {
      await fetchFormData({
        method: 'PATCH',
        path: 'member/data',
        data: formData,
      }).then((response) => {
        if (!response.error) {
          toast({
            title: 'Berhasil',
            description: 'Profil Anda telah berhasil diperbaharui',
            status: 'success',
            duration: 9000,
            isClosable: true,
          });
          getMemberData();
        } else {
          toast({
            title: 'Error',
            description: response.message,
            status: 'error',
            duration: 9000,
            isClosable: true,
          });
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      toast({
        title: 'Error',
        description: error.message,
        status: 'error',
        duration: 9000,
        isClosable: true,
      });
    }
  };

  const getMemberData = async () => {
    try {
      await fetchRequest({ method: 'GET', path: 'member' }).then((response) => {
        if (!response.error) {
          setMemberData(response);
          setPhoneNumber(response.phoneNumber);
          setExpiredDate(
            dayjs(response.membershipValidEnd).format('DD MMMM YYYY')
          );
          setEmail(response.email);
          setName(response.name);
          setIsSubscribe(response.subscribeNewsletter);
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMemberData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box>
      <Box h="30px" paddingLeft={{ base: '10px', lg: '3%' }} w="100%">
        <CustomBreadcrumb breadcrumbs={BREADCRUMB_PENGATURAN} />
      </Box>
      <Stack
        w={{ xl: '100%' }}
        direction={['column', 'row']}
        spacing={{ md: '50px', base: '30px' }}
        paddingLeft={{ base: '3%' }}
        paddingRight={{ base: '3%' }}
        paddingTop={{ base: '0px', lg: '20px' }}
      >
        <Box
          w={{ md: '20%' }}
          h="400px"
          display={{ md: 'inline', base: 'none' }}
        />
        <Box w="100%">
          <VStack w="100%" marginBottom="10px">
          
        <ImageLoader
          size={155}
          image={memberData?.photoUrl ||
            'https://www.seekpng.com/png/detail/966-9665317_placeholder-image-person-jpg.png'}
          callback={(image) => setNewPicture(image)} 
        />
<VStack align="start">
        <Text className="fontSemiBold" fontSize={{ lg: 'md', base: 'sm' }}>
          Name
        </Text>
        <InputGroup paddingTop="5px" zIndex={0}>
          <InputLeftElement
            pointerEvents="none"
            children={<Image src={imgUsernameIcon} w="30%" />}
            paddingTop="5px"
          />
          <Input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Masukkan Nama"
            _focus={{ boxShadow: 'none', borderColor: RED }}
            fontSize={{ lg: 'md', base: 'sm' }}
            value={name}
            onChange={(e: any) => setName(e.target.value)}
            errorBorderColor={RED}
            isInvalid={name === ''}
          />
        </InputGroup>

  <CustomButton
            text="SIMPAN"
            variant="red"
            icon="none"
            w="150px"
            onClick={handleSubmit}
          />
        </Box>
```

What do I need to add or change? I google it but still not found the answer how to insert cropped image result to code above to save when submit.

Comment: This looks like a [re-post of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77414891/need-help-to-get-cropped-image-to-upload). It is generally permitted to operate more than one account, but it helps curators here if you can stick to just one.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `react-cropper` dependancy.

In order for the library to work, we need to import it and its css file

```
import Cropper from "react-cropper";
import "cropperjs/dist/cropper.css";
```

With the Cropper component, we can pass a lot of props that fit our needs, for instance:

```
<Cropper
    src={avatarUrl}
    style={{ height: 400, width: 400 }}
    initialAspectRatio={4 / 3}
    minCropBoxHeight={100}
    minCropBoxWidth={100}
    guides={false}
    checkOrientation={false}
    onInitialized={(instance) => {
      setCropper(instance);
    }}
/>
<button onClick={getCropData}>Crop Image</button>
```

```
const getCropData = async () => {
    if (cropper) {
        const file = await fetch(cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL())
            .then((res) => res.blob())
            .then((blob) => {
              return new File([blob], "newAvatar.png", { type: "image/png" });
            });
        if (file) {
            authService
                .uploadAvatar(userId, file)
                .then(() => {
                  refetchUser(userId);
                  cancelEdit();
                })
                .catch((e) => alert(e));
        }
    }
};
```

Here, you can upload file with `formData.append('file', file)`;